# Maintaining div to have same effects like table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have now trying to move from the table way of building layout to div which I see a lot of debate on. I notice lots of people are asking to move to div. The issue I find with div for example below codes which I am referring to a template . MY issue is that on different resolution it looks different there is not like fix size. For eg.  in some resolution its just nice and some it shrink. What is the best solution to ensure it stay in every resolution which I know if I would go back to table it will work but that is not advisable I guess.

```
<body>


    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".top-nav.nav-collapse,.sidebar-nav.nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                 <img alt="Logo" src="img/logo20.png" /> 

                <!-- theme selector starts -->
                <div class="btn-group pull-right theme-container" >

                    <h5>User Name:  my demo</h5>
                    Logout
                </div>



            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  

        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">

            <!-- left menu starts -->
            <div class="span2 main-menu-span">
                <div class="well nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
                        <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet">Vtst1</li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="test1.php"><i class="icon-home"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Test1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="test2.php"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Test2</span></a></li>

                        <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet">Admin</li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="addM.php"><i class="icon-home"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Master</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="ajax-link" href="gridU.php"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">UD</span></a></li>


                        </ul>

                </div><!--/.well -->
            </div>
                        <!--/span-->
            <!-- left menu ends -->



            <div id="content" class="span10">
            <!-- content starts -->


            <div>
                <ul class="breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a> <span class="divider">/</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Forms</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <div class="row-fluid ">
                <div class="box span6">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2>Add Master</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <form class="form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>


                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="selectError3">Master Type</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <select id="selectError3">
                                    <option>T1</option>
                                    <option>T2</option>
                                    <option>T3</option>

                                  </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Master Serial Number</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                  <input type="text" id="inputSuccess">

                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-actions">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
                              </div>
                            </fieldset>
                          </form>

                    </div>
                </div><!--/span-->


              <div class="box span6 ">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2>Active Masters</h2>


                    </div>
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered  datatable">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>No</th>
                                  <th>Master Type</th>

                              </tr>
                          </thead>   
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td class="center">T1</td>
                                <td class="center">T111</td>
                                <td class="center">
                                    <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td class="center">T1</td>
                                <td class="center">T112</td>
                                <td class="center">
                                    <span class="label label-success">Active</span>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                                                  </tbody>
                         </table>
                    </div>
                </div><!--/span-->


              </div><!--/row-->




                    <!-- content ends -->
            </div><!--/#content.span10-->


            </div><!--/fluid-row-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive layout then you can give width to your divs in percent like if you want four divs then give width:25%; to each div
it is simplest way to get what you want or you can also shift to framework like bootstrap or pure css...

Comment: I dont get you what do you mean by give width 25%? I have read about this boostrap actually what is it about? IS it a template I am not so  clear on this. Yes I am using now css to manipulate around.

Comment: So looks like at the very top before this <div class="navbar"> I should add <div class="wrapper">. Should I fix the size of this div so it stays fix in every browser and resolution? With that fix then I think I can fix the width of every of mine div so they all stay fix in every resolution or browser?

Comment: Yes you can fix the width of your div.

Comment: Is the fix width a good resolution. Another thing I need a help here is exactly below this <div class="box span6 ">
                    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
                        <h2>Active Masters</h2> I want to have another div with with same format but with different content. Now when I create the div it goes below my form and not here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want a responsive layout (the components on the page shift and alter depending on the current viewing resolution). From the look of your `div` classes, you seem to be using Bootstrap. Bootstrap has a very lovely [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) that should fit the bill for what you're looking for.

In short, you would want to wrap the different segments in your page in a `row` and specify a `col`. Bootstrap divides your page into 12 equal segments and you can decide on what goes in each segment (`col`).

So, for example, your page would look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Left Menu Column -->
<div class="col-md-3">

    <!-- left menu starts -->
    <div class="span2 main-menu-span">
        <div class="well nav-collapse sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
                <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet">Vtst1</li>

                <li><a class="ajax-link" href="test1.php"><i class="icon-home"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Test1</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="ajax-link" href="test2.php"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Test2</span></a></li>

                <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet">Admin</li>
                <li><a class="ajax-link" href="addM.php"><i class="icon-home"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">Master</span></a></li>
                <li><a class="ajax-link" href="gridU.php"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i>  <span class="hidden-tablet">UD</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Center Content Column -->
<div class="col-md-6">

    <!-- Insert Content Here -->

</div>

<!-- Right Menu Column -->
<div class="col-md-3">

    <!-- Insert Content Here -->

</div>
```

Keep in mind that the `col-x-x` part can vary depending on what you want (see Bootstrap's [grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for specifics). I have not seen your CSS rules for `<div class="container-fluid">` and `<div class="row-fluid">`, but I'm pretty sure you won't be needing them for this simple layout; Bootstrap provides the proper CSS for you.

Hope this helps, and good on ya for leaving table layouts behind. :)

Comment: I confuse what is this boostrap is it a .css template? Yes this codes are based on a template and I have now updated my question with the full .css file too. So am I moving on the right track of not using table anymore?

Comment: I think I want to move away from the fluid container and rather go on a fix width what is your opinion on this. I feel I would better center page with fix width of my div? Another thing how can I make say in my sample

Comment: I had thought your `btn btn-navbar` was you using Bootstrap (it has classes exactly like that). I'd recommend against using fixed widths if you want your webpage to smoothly react with multiple resolutions; using that many media queries would be more trouble than it's worth. But, other than that, I'm not completely sure on what your question is asking. You wanted to know how to set up a responsive webpage, or...?

Comment: Yes I saw the .css file is too big for me to put here yes its following the bootstrap. The problem now with different resolution some time the box where my form is too big at other times it shrink looks horrible. That is why I plan at to have at the very top a wrapper div and center the whole page and fix width.

Comment: I see. Well, though I can't really see the actual page you're working with, I'd recommend looking into CSS Media Queries for fine-tuning on different pixel resolutions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). I hope that helps things a bit for ya.

Comment: @Actually I am using the boostrap well I can see it spread well on different resolution just hat some of div grow and shrink well but not the form elements so it look odd to have a smaller div and the form element are out of it. Due to that problem I am deciding to go on a fix width to be safe and retain a nice page on every resolution.

Comment: E.g based on my codes <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess">Master Serial Number</label> this element doesnt shrink so it stay and the box in where the whole form shrink so it looks very odd o smaller resolution. All other form element and even my grid table does not shrink. Thus these elements are not fluid like the divs where they are stored in.

Comment: any input on this please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the new `flexbox` approach to CSS layout. It does a good job of infusing the box model with the more helpful aspects of the `table` display:

- Vertically alignment is effortless
- Horizontal spacing is decoupled from the number of elements

And other advantages including:

- Ability to arbitrarily order elements
- Display elements in column vs. a row
- Finer control over how white-space is distributed